# problemas con onload html angular 2(typescript)

Tags: html, typescript

Colegas, tengo un problema, quiero hacer una trivia con preguntas dinamicas en un solo page, al inicio necesito ejecutar una funcion para poder asignarle valor a unas variables en el html, pero el onload no me funciona. esto es html con typescrypt con angular2. Alguna sugerencia?
[codigo TS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oebhj.jpg)

[image: CODIGO HTML]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes para pegar el código. Pensemos en dispositivos con pantallas chicas o personas con problemas de vista. Además, ¿podrías agregar lo que intentaste hasta ahora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy viendo que estas utilizando Ionic, en este framework existen los "Lifecyle events", que son métodos que se disparan durante el ciclo de vida de cada vista.

Intenta en lugar de llamarla desde la vista, hacer la llamada a tu método desde tu controlador, probablemente utilizando "`ionViewDidLoad()`" o "`ionViewDidEnter()`" dependiendo de cual se ajuste mejor a tus necesidades.

Te dejo el link a la documentación, busca en esa misma página Lifecycle Events y me dices si resuelve tu problema :)

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: MIL GRACIAS! EL ionViewDidLoad soluciono mi problema. Saludos